# No data when writing to csv from ubuntu server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm using ubuntu to run a script and pullout data from this server,this data has list of list of data in it. But after running the script it doesn't write anything on the csv file.

I'm running root and I have tried modifying the csv file directly from ubuntu and its working so we can eliminate the permission or access from ubuntu to CSV. Also I have tried running different script and it can able to write from CSV.

No trace traceback/error message occur when running the script, My verification are:

1. I tried running os.open/subprocess on pulling data but still the same result it not wring anything(not sure if try this is relevant.)
2. tried I solating the code, transfer the list of data and the write command and its working.
3. tried some suggestion forum in writing to CSV but still doesnt work.

I thing I havent tried is the encoding part? Do you think its related with this?

Sample of the code:

```
print ("\nRTR List: ",rtrlist)
print ("\nINT List: ",ilist)
print ("\nDESC List: ",dlist)
print ("\nBUN List: ",blist)

rtrlist = [[ele] for ele in rtrlist]

## EXPORT AS CSV
with open('intlist.csv', 'w', newline='') as updatecsv:
    write = csv.writer(updatecsv, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
    for cols in zip(rtrlist,ilist,dlist):
        rows = itertools.zip_longest(*cols, fillvalue='')
        write.writerows(rows)
print ("\n Done...csv file has been updated")
```

Print Result on last part before exportng.

```
RTR List:  ['r01.tp06', 'r02.m01', 'r01.m02']
INT List:  [['HundredGigE0/2/0/0', 'HundredGigE0/2/0/0.242', 'HundredGigE0/2/0/0.244 l2transport', 'HundredGigE0/2/0/1', 'HundredGigE0/2/0/0.244'], ['TenGigabitEthernet1/1/0.138'], ['TenGigE0/1/0/15']]
DESC List:  [['ALPHANUMERICWITHCHARAC;;;', 'ALPHANUMERICWITHCHARAC;;;', 'ALPHANUMERICWITHCHARAC;;;'], ['ALPHANUMERICWITHCHARAC;;;'], ['ALPHANUMERICWITHCHARAC;;;']]
BUN List:  ['', '', '']
```

Sanitized the desc. part but the output is alphanumeric with charac.

Note: I:m able to print the data correct.

Thankss

Comment: It's always nice if you can condense the code to a minimal sample that reproduces the same issue. I doubt all this code is needed to showcase the issue.

Comment: Change `list` of `list` in `ilist, dlist` to normalized `list` and do `write.writerows(itertools.zip_longest(rtrlist, ilist, dlist, fillvalue=''))`

Comment: @stovfl, you mean i ned to convert to flat list ? Do you have sample of the code?... also is there any issue using this list of list, it just tried this export part using the value from the last print and its working. also intertool has been added on my export part which I have posted. Thanks

Comment: its now working... hooooo :) problem is with the current location of my directory wherein the script pullout/move to different directory first.. so I have to put the absolute path when saving on CSV. Thanks all